# spring cloud stream - gcp pubsub binder maxFetchSize?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-stream-binder

try to use spring cloud gcp binder library polling messages from GCP pubsub topic.
ref from [streaming-vs-polled-input](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/main/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-stream.adoc#streaming-vs-polled-input). use **spring.cloud.stream.gcp.pubsub.default.consumer.maxFetchSize** poll get N message (maxFetchSize's value) at a time, but even i set up the property and set maxFetchSize to 2 or others. i alwasy got 1 message from topic, even the topic has other messages. Does anyone here has other idea?

- spring cloud version: 2021.0.3
- google spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies version: 3.3.0
- java: openjdk 11

```
# application.properties
spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.project-id= 
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location= 
spring.cloud.stream.default-binder=pubsub
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=iamatopic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.content-type=text/plain;charset=UTF-8
spring.cloud.stream.gcp.pubsub.default.consumer.maxFetchSize=3
```

```java
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.PollableMessageSource;

public interface PollableSink {
    @Input("input")
    PollableMessageSource input();
}
```

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.PollableMessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

import com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.support.AcknowledgeablePubsubMessage;
import com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.support.GcpPubSubHeaders;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Configuration
@EnableBinding(PollableSink.class)
@Slf4j
public class PollConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    PollableMessageSource destIn;

    PolledMessageHandler messageHandler = new PolledMessageHandler();

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void poller() {
        log.info("start polling ");
        destIn.poll(this.messageHandler, ParameterizedTypeReference.forType(String.class));
        log.info("end polling ");
    }

    static class PolledMessageHandler implements MessageHandler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) {
            AcknowledgeablePubsubMessage ackableMessage = (AcknowledgeablePubsubMessage) message.getHeaders()
                    .get(GcpPubSubHeaders.ORIGINAL_MESSAGE);
            ackableMessage.ack();

            System.out.println("get payload : " + message.getPayload());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you always get 1 message even if you set `spring.cloud.stream.gcp.pubsub.default.consumer.maxFetchSize ` to higher values e.g. 10?

Comment: try to set maxFetchSize eg. 3 or 5, and topic has 10 messages. Try to use spring integration (PubsubinboundChannelAdapter) set maxMessagesPerPoll  (@Poller) property, that's worked, even i call PubSubTemplate and set maxFetchSize property, that's worked,too. But i can not understand why use spring-cloud-stream-gcp-pubsub-binder doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `spring.cloud.stream.poller.maxMessagesPerPoll` value -- it's 1 by default in Spring Cloud Stream.

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_polling_configuration_properties

Comment: the result got 1 record, either setting `spring.cloud.stream.poller.maxMessagesPerPoll` (deprecated starting version 3.2 ) or setting `spring.integration.poller.maxMessagesPerPoll`

Comment: I've tested polling by adding `spring.cloud.stream.gcp.pubsub.default.consumer.maxFetchSize=10` to [this sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/7ce3b7f04d856a9d6ba015a465091ee53affba20/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-polling-sample/src/main/resources/application.properties), and also modifying the source to output a large batch of messages. The polled sink application behaved as expected -- it pulled up to 10 messages at a time from Pub/Sub. The Spring Integration settings were not necessary.